# In Windows Phone 8, How can i get the Background Color property of a button?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-phone-8

In Windows Phone 8, How can i get the Background Color property of a button?

```
<Button x:Name="btn" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="#FFF30808"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok. Don't know if it is the fastest way, but here it is

```
Color MyColor = ((SolidColorBrush)btn.Background).Color;
```